# Filtering previous month data with case statement

Tags: oracle, date, case

These are my available attributes:

```
DT_CURRENT_DT Month Year
11-OCT-18     10    2018
12-OCT-18     10    2018
13-OCT-18     10    2018
14-OCT-18     10    2018
15-OCT-18     10    2018
16-OCT-18     10    2018
17-OCT-18     10    2018
```

I need a logic that will pull last month data based on sysdate.

```
where DT_CURRENT_DT >=  trunc (sysdate, 'MM') - interval '1' month
and DT_CURRENT_DT <   trunc (sysdate, 'MM')
```

However when sysdate = November 2018 then data must be pulled from October 15th till end of October. For other months it must behave as code above.

UPDATE (NOV 11) - CASE code version:

```
WHERE  DT_CURRENT_DT >= CASE 
                       WHEN extract ( month from trunc (sysdate, 'MM')) = 11 and extract ( year from trunc (sysdate, 'MM')) = 2018
                       THEN to_date('15-OCT-2018')
                       ELSE  trunc(sysdate, 'MM') - interval '1' month
                       END
AND DT_CURRENT_DT <   trunc (sysdate, 'MM')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the `where` clause to the following:

```
where DT_CURRENT_DT >= trunc (sysdate, 'MM') - interval '1' month
  and DT_CURRENT_DT < trunc (sysdate, 'MM')
  and (
       trunc(sysdate, 'MM') != to_date('01-NOV-2018')
       or extract(day from DT_CURRENT_DT) >= 15
      );
```

Comment: great thanks! I had to change `month(current_date)` to `EXTRACT year`. That way in November 2017 I will get entire October. The rule to extract last month date starting 15th day was to happen only when sysdate is November 2018. For every other case it should pull entire last month: `where DT_CURRENT_DT >= trunc (to_date('06-NOV-17'), 'MM') - interval '1' month
  and DT_CURRENT_DT < trunc (to_date('06-NOV-17'), 'MM')
  and (
       extract (year from (to_date('06-NOV-17'))) != 2018
       or extract (day from (DT_CURRENT_DT)) >= 15 
      )`

Comment: I have changed the answer. Is the query now doing what you expect?

Comment: I noticed my first `where` logic didn't take entire logic into account. Your code is working as expected!!! Since `case` statement is acting exactly the same wanted to ask what is the difference. Is it performance wise to use `where` I understand?

Comment: I don't know if there's a difference in performance, but there shouldn't be. Choose what you think is more readable.